# /proc/kcore shows in 13Exabytes PPC platform

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am using a PPC 64 bit architecture system with 4G of RAM. My concern is that the size of virtual memory has increased to 13 Exabytes, which exceeds the expected range for a 64 bit addressing machine, leading to a potential system reset. Can anyone provide insights on this?

Here is my program header values:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  NOTE           0x00000000000000e8 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x000000000000158c 0x0000000000000000         0x0
  LOAD           0xc000000000002000 0x8000000000000000 0xffffffffffffffff
                 0x0000040000000000 0x0000040000000000  RWE    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0xc000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000100000000 0x0000000100000000  RWE    0x1000
```

I ran the following command to obtain this:

```
ls -la /proc/kcore
-r-------- 1 root root 13835062453328683008 Jun 14 14:23 /proc/kcore
```

Comment: "... 13 Exabytes, which exceeds the expected range for a 64 bit addressing machine" - This value is less then 2^64. why do you think that it exceeds expected range for a 64 bit addressing machine?